# Need help for approach to be used for implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I have question related to how I should develop a scenario in spring boot.

I have one class (say `SingleObject`) having some fields in it. I want to create another object from `SingleObject` (say `JsonObject`) having some `Json` structure derived from values of fields in `SingleObject`.

For this conversion I am using static method of a Class (say `Converter`); where method takes input of `SingleObject` and returns an object of `JsonObject`.

How should I implement this scenario in spring?

Should I use `@Configuration` annotation for `Converter` Class with `@Bean` annotation for method which returns `JsonObject`?

If I have to use `@Configuration` annotation, how should I collect that bean in my main method for further processing?

Comment: While the method is static you would not the object and so no need to annotate. If it is not static, you can create bean just annotating with `@Component` or you can either use `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotation and define beans in the class

Comment: looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903053/difference-between-component-and-configuration-in-spring-3

Comment: Thank you Amidala for your response. If I am not using static can you explain me how should I use spring boot configuration annotation?

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` should be fine. The `JsonObject` bean will be autowired if you specify `SingleObject` as a dependency (i.e. parameter).

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public SingleObject single() { return new SingleObject(); }

    @Bean
    public JsonObject json(SingleObject single) {
        return Converter.convert(single);
    }
}
```

You probably shouldn't access these beans from your main method, as your main method will necessarily be static and it requires a bit of a hack to do so: [Accessing spring beans in static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537851/accessing-spring-beans-in-static-method)

Comment: If I am fetching say 10 objects from DB as `SingleObject` and by passing it as a List to convert method and  getting List<JsonObject> then using @Bean annotation would be appropriate?

Comment: @YogeshGavali Not really. A `List` shouldn't usually be a bean. You might want some higher level class e.g. `class SomeService { private List<SingleObject> objects; public List<JsonObject> getJson() {... } }`. The service is a bean, and is responsible for fetching and storing the data as well as converting it.

Comment: How would you wire the different objects of `SingleObject` ?