# Helper Class Spring Boot with Environment Values

Tags: java, spring-boot, helper

I would like to create a helper class, but it just failed..
The error : java.lang.NullPointerException: null

When i do this without making a static class (with autowired) it works without problem. But it's a helper class, i think the static class is the better thing.

Thanks for help

Helper.java

```
public final class UrlHelper {
    
    @Autowired
    private static Environment bean;
    
    public static String method(String projet) {    
        return "titi"+ bean.getProperty("property.name");
    }
}
```

And in my service, i use it like this :

```
String list = getRequest.getHTTPRequest(UrlHelper.method(projet));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing spring beans in static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537851/accessing-spring-beans-in-static-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring, the `@Autowired` annotation allows you to resolve and inject *beans* into other *beans*. In your case, the `UrlHelper` class is not a bean and therefore, your `Environment` is not injected (stays **null**), hence the error. You have two options:

1. Make the `UrlHelper` a bean using `@Component`, `@Service`, etc. This will make your class non-static.
2. Keep the `UrlHelper` static, and pass the `Environment` as parameter. This, I believe, is the more correct approach. The Environment can be injected in the class calling the static method.

Comment: 2 . If i inject Environment as parameter it's not better than using environment in my service.. :(

Comment: It is. It makes sense from a design point of view that your helper class "helps" you do something, when provided with an Environment instance. This allows the class to work on any Environment you provide it, making it more versatile (as a helper class should be).

Comment: I want that the Environment stays in the helper class, not to inject it from a service ( because the helper will help me to build hundred of url)

Comment: Then you have no option, but use 1. Make your helper class a bean and remove the "static" keyword from its method. You can only inject your Environment in a bean.

Comment: Just Make the Helper class using @Component, but the class still static. I can use the helper by UrlHelper.Foo() .